# XmlSerializer Error, bytes array, List and InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, mtom

I found a weird behavior with XmlSerializer in C#, an someone help me?
I want this XML in SOAP/MTOM, and I need the xop:Include outside any other XMLElement:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/635913361387292553" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
    <List>1</List>
    <List>2</List>
</Root>
```

Here my C# code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var simulatedFile = new byte[800];
    new Random().NextBytes(simulatedFile);
    var root = new Root {List = new List<string> {"1","2"}, Bytes = simulatedFile};

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    using (var mtomInMemory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateMtomWriter(mtomInMemory, Encoding.UTF8, int.MaxValue, string.Empty))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, root);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mtomInMemory.ToArray()));
    }

    Console.Read();
}
public class Root
{
    [XmlText]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

The Error I have is:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll There
>   was an error reflecting type 'Program.Root'. Cannot serialize object
>   of type 'Program.Root'. Consider changing type of XmlText member
>   'Program.Root.Bytes' from System.Byte[] to string or string array.

But I need to let my Bytes array to contain **file binary** because with MTOM, it will be serialized by the **CreateMtomWriter in base64** if the Length is less that 768 byte or in **xop:Include** if more than 768 bytes.

I want it to be encoded as a direct child of Root Element, not wrapped in any other Element.

If in the class Root, i put only the Bytes or the List property, it works perfectly, but if i put both, it does not.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Where would you want that byte array to be encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft:
Thanks for reporting this issue. This is by design. The array of bytes cannot be text value. Please try to workaround this issue e.g. using string.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have encountered an [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) bug.

If I change the class to *remove* the `List` property, like so:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlText]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

Then `XmlSerializer` will serialize it successfully with the byte array automatically represented as a base 64 string:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">AAECAwQFBgcICQ==</Root>
```

And instead, if I change the class to make the `XmlText` property be a `string`-valued proxy property that translates the byte array from and to base 64, then `XmlSerializer` will *again* serialize it successfully **and identically**:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Base64Bytes
    {
        get
        {
            return Bytes == null ? null : Convert.ToBase64String(Bytes);
        }
        set
        {
            Bytes = value == null ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

Indeed, the documentation for [`XmlTextAttribute.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly indicates that byte arrays are one of the data types supported by [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Neverthess, the combination of an `[XmlText] byte [] Byte { get; set; }` property with any other `[XmlElement]` property in the same class causes the `XmlSerializer` constructor to throw an exception.  You might want to [report a problem to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx) since there is no reason for this not to work.

In the meantime, you can use the workaround of a string-valued proxy property as is shown above.